# How can I open a URL in Google Chrome from the terminal in OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, terminal

How can I open a URL in Google Chrome from the terminal in OS X?

This is what I'm trying:

```
/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" --args 'http://google.com/'
```

It focuses Chrome but does not open the URL.

Comment: why do you reference the open programm by it's path? It's aliased by default!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you remove the `--args` it seems to work fine, since `--args` can only affect things on first launch (it changes what main gets called with)

Comment: weird. seems like i used to have to use them. thanks.

Answer (score 66):

Actually for me, the command is not working with the "--args" being present so the command working for me is

```
/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" 'http://google.com/'
```

OS X version: 10.6.8

Comment: can you pipe string in place google

Answer (score 50):

If you set Google Chrome as your default browser

```
open http://google.com/
```

will just do the trick.

OS X version: 10.8.4

Comment: OS X 10.10 Yosemite as well.

Comment: This only works if google chrome is your default browser.  If you're using safari, firefox or another option but want to open the URL with chrome you'll need one of the other options.

Comment: good answer, now how do I do this in a new Chrome window?

Answer (score 12):

You can use

`open -a "Google Chrome" index.html`

or, to put it in a shell script (e.g. ~/bin/chrome)

- edit the file ~/bin/chrome, and put the following in it

  `open -a "Google Chrome" "$*"`
- make the file executable by running the following in a terminal

  `chmod 700 ~/bin/chrome`
- then run the following to open a file in chrome from the terminal

  `chrome /path/to/some/file`

[Pulled from here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/83632/7079)

Comment: function chrome(){
  open -a "Google Chrome" "$*" 
}

Answer (score 7):

I've an alias for google

```
function google() { open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ "http://www.google.com/search?q= $1"; }
```

Comment: that's a great idea :)

Comment: for zsh: ``chrome() {
    open -a "Google Chrome" "http://www.google.com/search?q=$1";
}``

Answer (score 7):

There are several helpful answers here but none that contain the complete info for opening a URL in Chrome in both cases whether it is or is not the default browser.

1. Open a URL in the default browser (could be Chrome):

   ```
   open http://www.example.com
   ```
2. Open a URL in Chrome always (using the app name):

   ```
   open -a "Google Chrome" http://www.example.com
   ```
3. Open a URL in Chrome always (using the app path alternative syntax):

   ```
   open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ http://example.com
   ```
4. Open a URL in Chrome always (using the bundle identifier alternative syntax):

   ```
   open -b com.google.chrome http://www.example.com
   ```
5. Open a URL in Chrome in an incognito window always:

   From `man open`, it would seem that you should be able to do it like this (but alas it does not seem to get the incognito option to Chrome):

   ```
   open -a "Google Chrome" http://example.com/ --args --incognito
   ```

   However, you can do it by passing the Chrome [command line switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) directly to the Chrome binary:

   ```
   /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --incognito http://example.com
   ```

Comment: **This answer,** your 5th point, but without `--incognito` - is what I came looking for, and could not find elsewhere. I was wondering how to bypass `open` (which does not support `chrome-extension://`) - so I could do like so, `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome 'chrome-extension://<gobbledygook>/views/default.html#/'` ... where I've copied the URL from an extension. I'm using this to open Jironimo (for JIRA) and OneTab, when I `cd` into work-project directory for first time each day.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve something similar to @driftcatcher but his method won't work for me (macOS 11.0.1, Chrome 90.0.4430.72) when trying to open a chrome:// scheme, it just opens a new window with a blank tab. Some security measure maybe? If anyone knows a workaround, I'd appreciate the ping.

Comment: @lima It does seem like the browser prevents loading the `chrome://` scheme programmatically for security purposes.  https://twitter.com/anatudor/status/1099590311540609024

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston Thanks for looking into it. I suspect something can be done using osascript, but I ended up just quoting the URL and calling it a day.

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of the `--args`. `open` already knows how to handle URLs.

Answer (score 2):

this is my method.

1. Update **~/.bash_profile** and add the **chrome** function below:

   ```
   function chrome(){ 
       local site=""
       if [[ -f "$(pwd)/$1" ]]; then
           site="$(pwd)/$1"
       elif [[ "$1" =~ "^http" ]]; then
           site="$1"
       else
           site="http://$1"
       fi  
       /usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" "$site"; 
   }
   ```
2. Load **~/.bash_profile**:
   `source ~/.bash_profile`
3. Lunch chrome and open a site:
   `chrome www.google.com`
4. Open a local site:
   `chrome LOCAL_SITE_PATH`

Answer (score 1):

In *macos Sierra 10.12.6* .If chrome is your default browser. You can do this by

`open  index.html`

Answer (score 0):

Using `chrome-cli`:

```
chrome-cli open <url>  (Open url in new tab)
chrome-cli open <url> -n  (Open url in new window)
chrome-cli open <url> -i  (Open url in new incognito window)
chrome-cli open <url> -t <id>  (Open url in specific tab)
chrome-cli open <url> -w <id>  (Open url in new tab in specific window)
```